# What language was it written?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

Different languages are used in coding the blockchain these days. Which was used in coding BTC and how is it superior to others?

Answer (score 2):

The original bitcoin client created by Satoshi was coded in C++, and is maintained here, now known as Bitcoin Core: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/